# How to reject all the promises if one of them gets rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, promise

I have this piece of code

```
exports.myFunction = async () => {
  const array = []
  try {
    var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
    var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        array.push(1)
        array.push(2)
        array.push(3)
      }, 2000);
    });

    var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject("foo");
      }, 2000);
    });
    
    const [a, b, c] = await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])
    console.log(a, b, c)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({array})
    console.log({err})
  }
}
exports.myFunction()
```

It pushed the data in `array` even after promise gets rejected in the `p3`. I want it to be in initial state if any of the promises gets rejected. How can I do that?

Reason behind asking the question...

I have multiple Mongo queries

```
const [a, b] = await Promise.all([
  User.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: { isDone: true }}),
  Notification.aggregate([...])
])
```

Sometimes I get error in `Notification.aggregate` at that time and I don't want to update the `User`.

Comment: The result of the promise chain will be a rejection, but that doesn't mean any of the running promise tasks will be canceled or their side effects undone.

Comment: Promises are just a notification mechanism for some async operation. You *cannot* affect the async operation through a promise. You cannot stop/abort/cancel it or otherwise end the operation prematurely. You can combine the promise with others and reject that combined promise but that doesn't affect the async operation, just means that the combined result is now considered in an error state.

Comment: @deceze Yes so how can I do that? I want all the fulfilled promises in initial state if any of then gets rejected.

Comment: Don't have side effects in your promises, but purely do return/resolve-values.

Comment: @Profer unless your async operation supports some sort of cancellation - you cannot. Even then, you cannot do it through the *promise*. You need some sort of handle to the operation.

Comment: If the update operation is dependent on the aggregation, then you simply can't execute them in parallel and need to aggregate first, then run the update. Or do a transaction, if that's possible, and roll back the update.

Comment: @deceze Javascript is a vast language there should be some sort of function in Promise like`Promise.something` which must do this.

Comment: @deceze They are not depended... but still I want if there is something in JS which does this

Comment: Timing-wise the update will probably be done before the aggregation! They're started in parallel, with the update in fact being triggered first! Promises don't know anything about the details of the tasks, so they cannot *undo* the update. From what you're describing, the update *is* dependent on the aggregation, and it's not the job nor capability of `Promise.all` to resolve that dependency.

Comment: @Profer "*Javascript is a vast language there should be some sort of function in Promise likePromise.something which must do this.*" there isn't because Promises aren't what you think they are. Again, they don't *control* the async operation. They were never intended to. No matter how much you wish a promise is a control mechanism, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to roll back changes in a desired case, you need to use the transaction mechanism https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/.

To catch when only one promise has been rejected, you can use `Promise.allSettled`:

```js
const promises = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.reject('error'),
  Promise.resolve(3),
];

const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

const rejected = results.some(result => result.status === 'rejected');

if (rejected) {
  console.log(rejected.reason);
} else {
  const values = results.map(result => result.value);

  console.log(values);
}
```